# Connected components of bounded linear operators of $V = (\mathcal C(U(1), \mathbb C) , \lVert \cdot \rVert_\infty)$

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, path-connected

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764069/is-mathcallv-path-connected).

Consider the complex Banach space $V=(\mathcal C(U(1), \mathbb C), \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$ where $\mathcal C(U(1), \mathbb C)$ is the space of continuous complex maps defined on the unit circle endowed with the sup norm.

Define $G$ as the operator that maps an element $f \in V$ to the element $G(f)$ such that

$$G(f) : z \in U(1) \mapsto zf(z) \in \mathbb C.$$

**Is $G$ in the same connected component that the identity in the subset of bounded linear invertible operators of $V$ denoted by $\mathcal{L}(V)^*$**

*Note: I moved this question @mathoverflow and deleted the math.stackexchange one.*

Comment: In fact the general linear group of this Banach space is contractible. There is a proof in [this article of Mityagin](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM1970v025n05ABEH003814/pdf). A different article of his promises a simpler argument but I couldn't find an online copy.